# Why does Lost have an unequal number of episodes among all seasons?

Tags: production, lost, lost-missing-pieces

Lost seems to have an unequal number of episodes across its various seasons:

- season 1 - 25 episodes
- season 2 - 24 episodes
- season 3 - 23 episodes
- season 4 - 14 episodes
- season 5 - 17 episodes
- season 6 - 18 episodes.

Even [Lost: Missing Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost:_Missing_Pieces) has 13 episodes.

Why did Lost always have an unequal number of episode among all of the seasons? I heard about a hiatus between the 3rd and 4th seasons but why does it happen with all the seasons?

Comment: Is this really unique to Lost? This seems to be the case with a number of shows.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I have not seen this much of variation in other show i have followed.

Comment: There's no reason to presuppose that the story arc for every season will neatly fit into an exact number of episodes, particularly not one determined 5 seasons ago.  Etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Season 1 and 2 were supposed to have 24 episodes (the "normal" amount of episodes for a network show), but for season 1 the finale became a double-length episode.

With respect to season 3: they planned for 22 episodes, but the finale became a double-length episode. [Wikipedia does note the remarkable broadcast schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(season_3)):

> In response to fan complaints about scheduling in the previous
>   seasons, ABC decided to air the episodes without reruns, albeit in two
>   separate blocks. In the United States, the first block consisted of
>   six episodes aired on Wednesdays at 9:00 pm and after a twelve week
>   break, the season continued with the remaining 16 episodes at 10:00
>   pm.

With respect to season 4, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(season_4)):

> The season was **originally planned to contain 16 episodes; eight were
>   filmed before the start of the 2007–2008 Writers Guild of America
>   strike**. Following the strike's resolution, it was announced that
>   **only five more episodes would be produced to complete the season**;
>   however, the season finale's script was so long that **network
>   executives approved the production of a 14th episode as part of a
>   three-hour season finale** split over two nights.

Season 5's 17 are due to the two "missing" episodes from season 4 being re-distributed to season 5 and season 6.

With respect to season 6, again [quoting Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(season_6)):

> Beginning with the 2007–2008 television season, the final 48 episodes
>   would have been aired as three seasons with 16 episodes each, with
>   Lost concluding in its sixth season. Due to 2007–2008 Writers Guild of
>   America strike, the fourth season featured 14 episodes, and season 5
>   had 17 episodes. **Season six was planned to have 17 episodes**, too.
>   However, on June 29, 2009 it was announced that **the final season would
>   feature an additional hour**, making the number of episodes 18.

Comment: The Writer's Guild of America strike threw a monkey wrench in several other shows as well, like [season 4 of The Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Office_(U.S._season_4)#Production).  It also allowed things like [Dr Horrible's Sing Along Blog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Horrible%27s_Sing-Along_Blog) to exist (it was produced during the strike)